# Merging geojson line geometries within a single sf object based on shared feature value (conditional st_combine?)

Tags: r, visualization, geojson, r-sf

I am working on a personal project trying to combine open data sources from municipal government. I have practically no prior experience with working with geospatial data, so visualising insights using this has proven to be a challenge.

Essentially, I am attempting to combine two sources of data.

The first is a classic .csv dataset of traffic events - I have so far spent my time pre-processing and analysing this, and feel quite comfortable with that. Of note is that the location of traffic events is given by a **street_name**, which I have standardised and separated into the *street* column, rather than coordinates or other identifiers. The other columns provide more information regarding the event of that row (for a total of approx. 900k rows).

Based on that, I looked for the most detailed dataset of the streets in question. Unfortunately, the one fitting my needs is almost too detailed - most of the streets are separated into smaller sections, to which I cannot deaggregate my event data. To properly show the data, then, I would need to merge all the LINESTRING geometries (in the **geometry** column) which share the same **street_name** to one continuous line, so that I could then use the street name as a key to match the whole street to any events occuring on it. Relatedly, the lines also have a **Shape_Length** property, of which I am unsure (given my unfamiliarity) if it must be summed manually, will be recalculated post-hoc, or is even necessary in the first place as long as the coordinates of the geometry match up.

All in all, the file that is proving a challenge for me looks something like this:

```
    dput(head(tsk_data, 5))
    structure(list(OBJECTID = 1:5, MKN = c("NN7453", "NN7452", "NN7451", 
    "NN7450", "NN7449"), USEK_NAZ = c("Charvátova-pokračování", 
    "Jablunkovská-pokračování", "Vršovická-Vršovická", "Točitá-pokračování", 
    "Antala Staška-Panuškova"), DALNICE = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
        TRIDASIL = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), TRIDAMK = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 
        0L, 0L), TYPKOMUNIK = c(0L, 19L, 21L, 19L, 19L), SMEROVOST = c(3L, 
        0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), POSKYT = c("HMP-TSK", "HMP-TSK", "HMP-TSK", 
        "HMP-TSK", "HMP-TSK"), Shape_Length = c(0.000726434480686331, 
        0.000688214170240968, 0.000104557565766303, 0.000500798213310109, 
        0.000861111526683966), geometry = structure(list(structure(c(14.4208013050001, 
        14.420701298, 14.4204086710001, 14.420336804, 14.420311828, 
        14.420252503, 50.0818569370001, 50.081835529, 50.0818334850001, 
        50.0818486040001, 50.081881234, 50.082089963), dim = c(6L, 
        2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(14.508402357, 
        14.5084069600001, 14.5089489260001, 50.1391580700001, 50.1390268330001, 
        50.1388987450001), dim = 3:2, class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", 
        "sfg")), structure(c(14.449696617, 14.4497051230001, 50.06592993, 
        50.066034141), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", 
        "sfg")), structure(c(14.4354879690001, 14.4349871740001, 
        50.0397977040001, 50.0397959100001), dim = c(2L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
        "LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(14.4368686030001, 14.4368403500001, 
        14.4368092660001, 14.436791758, 14.4367725560001, 14.436084587, 
        50.040384198, 50.040429573, 50.0405017510001, 50.0405103030001, 
        50.0405145030001, 50.0404624990001), dim = c(6L, 2L), class = c("XY", 
        "LINESTRING", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_LINESTRING", "sfc"
        ), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 14.420252503, 
        ymin = 50.0397959100001, xmax = 14.5089489260001, ymax = 50.1391580700001
        ), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(input = "WGS 84", 
            wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n    DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic latitude (Lat)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic longitude (Lon)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(OBJECTID = NA_integer_, 
    MKN = NA_integer_, USEK_NAZ = NA_integer_, DALNICE = NA_integer_, 
    TRIDASIL = NA_integer_, TRIDAMK = NA_integer_, TYPKOMUNIK = NA_integer_, 
    SMEROVOST = NA_integer_, POSKYT = NA_integer_, Shape_Length = NA_integer_
    ), levels = c("constant", "aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"), row.names = c(NA, 
    5L), class = c("sf", "data.frame"))
```

After some searching, the closest I have found to what I think must be done is the *st_combine* function. However, as far as I can tell, the default behaviour is to collapse all of the geometries in *x*, which would defeat the point of my project. Instead, I would like to only collapse/combine those which share the same value in the **street name (MKN)** column. I tried approaching this via subsetting, including with for loops, but the outputted list seemed to not follow the original structure (again, I am unfamiliar with the expected object types and formats) and the lat and long coordinates seemed rounded to the point of unusability.

To reiterate, I am trying to find a way to merge the geometries of lines (not points or polygons) within an existing geojson conditionally based on a shared value in one of their properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to only collapse/combine those which share the same value in the street name (MKN) column.

With `sf` objects you can apply the same *split-apply-combine* logic as with regular data.frames and tibbles, either through `aggregate()` if you are more into base R; or with `group_by()` / `summarise()` when leaning towards Tidyverse. For the example, let's use `roxel` dataset from `sfnetworks`, check how a number of features and geometry type are changed after `summarise()`:

```r
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# include only named sections and certain street types: 
streets <- sfnetworks::roxel %>%  
  filter(`type` %in% c("residential", "secondary", "service") & !is.na(name)) %>% 
  arrange(name)

# every geometry is a LINESTRING:
streets
#> Simple feature collection with 466 features and 2 fields
#> Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 7.522625 ymin: 51.94151 xmax: 7.546705 ymax: 51.95945
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> # A tibble: 466 × 3
#>    name               type                                              geometry
#>    <chr>              <fct>                                     <LINESTRING [°]>
#>  1 Aloysia-Delsen-Weg residential         (7.533476 51.95815, 7.533743 51.95769)
#>  2 Aloysia-Delsen-Weg residential          (7.533743 51.95769, 7.53405 51.95717)
#>  3 Aloysia-Delsen-Weg residential (7.534638 51.95841, 7.535086 51.95852, 7.5351…
#>  4 Aloysia-Delsen-Weg residential         (7.531509 51.95858, 7.531778 51.95807)
#>  5 Aloysia-Delsen-Weg residential         (7.531778 51.95807, 7.531966 51.95773)
#>  6 Aloysia-Delsen-Weg residential         (7.531778 51.95807, 7.532206 51.95805)
#>  7 Aloysia-Delsen-Weg residential (7.534638 51.95841, 7.534876 51.95799, 7.5348…
#>  8 Aloysia-Delsen-Weg residential (7.534875 51.95795, 7.534819 51.95792, 7.5337…
#>  9 Aloysia-Delsen-Weg residential (7.532206 51.95805, 7.532552 51.95804, 7.5329…
#> 10 Aloysia-Delsen-Weg residential         (7.533287 51.95812, 7.533476 51.95815)
#> # ℹ 456 more rows

# text on every geometry
ggplot(streets, aes(label = name)) +
  geom_sf(aes(color = name), linewidth = 1.5) +
  geom_sf_text(size = 2, alpha = .8) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
#> Warning in st_point_on_surface.sfc(sf::st_zm(x)): st_point_on_surface may not
#> give correct results for longitude/latitude data
```

[image]

```r
# union of streets by name, not all streets have multiple sections,
# this leaves us with mixed geometries (LINESTRING + MULTILINESTRING)
streets_union <- streets %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  summarise() %>% 
  arrange(name)

# from 466 features down to 75:
streets_union
#> Simple feature collection with 75 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: GEOMETRY
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 7.522625 ymin: 51.94151 xmax: 7.546705 ymax: 51.95945
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> # A tibble: 75 × 2
#>    name                                                                 geometry
#>    <chr>                                                          <GEOMETRY [°]>
#>  1 Aloysia-Delsen-Weg     MULTILINESTRING ((7.533476 51.95815, 7.533743 51.9576…
#>  2 Alte Dorfstrasse       LINESTRING (7.532418 51.95481, 7.532606 51.95483, 7.5…
#>  3 Alter Gemeindeplatz    LINESTRING (7.532275 51.9556, 7.533447 51.95562, 7.53…
#>  4 Am Meckelbach          MULTILINESTRING ((7.530726 51.94829, 7.531044 51.9486…
#>  5 Am Rohrbusch                 LINESTRING (7.541581 51.94878, 7.54253 51.94911)
#>  6 An der Kleikuhle       LINESTRING (7.529509 51.9569, 7.530009 51.95695, 7.53…
#>  7 Anna-Peuler-Weg        MULTILINESTRING ((7.531971 51.95867, 7.532265 51.9587…
#>  8 Auf dem Dorn           MULTILINESTRING ((7.531428 51.95399, 7.531267 51.9542…
#>  9 Bertolt-Brecht-Strasse MULTILINESTRING ((7.536333 51.94844, 7.536385 51.9481…
#> 10 Bredeheide             MULTILINESTRING ((7.53881 51.95679, 7.540002 51.95732…
#> # ℹ 65 more rows

# text on every geometry
ggplot(streets_union, aes(label = name)) +
  geom_sf(aes(color = name), linewidth = 1.5) +
  geom_sf_text(size = 3, alpha = .8) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
#> Warning in st_point_on_surface.sfc(sf::st_zm(x)): st_point_on_surface may not
#> give correct results for longitude/latitude data
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you - I take your response to also implicitly suggest that my worry that about having to keep a Shape_Length parameter is unfounded, and the geometry contains everything necessary to then render the geom properly?

Comment: Attributes (all other columns besides geometry columns) are just to store non-spatial information, you can drop / add / rename / alter those as you would with any regular data.frame, they do not affect stored geometries in any way. As you see, `summarise()` drops all columns that are not part of grouping / agration anyway. If you need total length and want to save few CPU cycles, you could use something like `group_by(MKN) %>% summarise(lengh_sum = sum(Shape_Length))` to get sum of length during that same step.